# How to improve my situation with RecursionError(Python, PyQt4)?

Tags: python, qt, recursion, pyqt

**So, i have a function, which aim is to color words if they are surrounded by commas.**

```
    def __init__(...something):
        ...something
        self.user_input = QtGui.QTextEdit(self)
        self.user_input.textChanged.connect(self.check_text)
        ...something

    def check_text(self):
        text = self.user_input.toPlainText().strip()
        comma = ","
        if comma in text: 
            elements_quantity = text.count(comma)
            sites = text.split(comma)
            sites_quantity = len(sites)
            done_sites = [] 
            if sites_quantity > elements_quantity:
                done_sites = sites[:elements_quantity]
            else:
                done_sites = sites
        else:
            done_sites = [""]

        for site in done_sites:
            new_site = "<strong>{site}</strong>"
            text = text.replace(site, new_site.format(site=site))
        self.user_input.setHtml(text)
        self.user_input.moveCursor(QtGui.QTextCursor.End)
```

**And, when I start writing, I have RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object each time I write a symbol.**
**What I should to do to improve it?**

Comment: you should not update `user_input` in `check_text`, because each time you call `setHtml` (or `moveCursor`) it emits signal ` textChanged ` and you are again in `check_text` method with the text you just edited. If you need to update text that way - `disconnect` signal before writing and connect again after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just block signals when you try to change the text

```
self.blockSignal(True)
self.user_input.setHtml(text)
self.user_input.moveCursor(QtGui.QTextCursor.End)
self.blockSignal(False)
```